# How I can fix such bug from Google Play Console?

Tags: android

I received such log at Google Play Console:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: ControllerMessenger
Process: de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet, PID: 31798
kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    at de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet.notepad.NoteData.getRemarksList(NoteData.kt:282)
    at de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet.notepad.NoteData.access$getRemarksList(NoteData.kt:26)
    at de.jobnetzwerk.jobnet.notepad.NoteData$updateRemark$1.onResponse(NoteData.kt:121)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.a(Interrogator.java:19)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:169)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:161)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.a(UiControllerImpl.java:141)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.a(Tap.java:6)
    at androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:20)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:9)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:79)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.a(ViewInteraction.java:97)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:3)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

below problematic line (num. 282):

```
Singleton.apiService().getNoteRecords("Bearer " + context!!.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0)?.getString("access_token", ""), noteID!!).enqueue(object : Callback<List<RemarkModelNotepad>> {
```

at this line I start getting data from server API. Which part can create a problem?

### UPDATE

My problem in generall is connected with safe-types at kotlin. I think that it will be solved by adding `?` or `!!` but I don't kno where I have to add this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @JosephSible, I have just updated my question. I saw the question which you post here but it didn't help me :(

Comment: From where you invoke `getNoteRecords `?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman, from api interface, you think here can be my problem?

Comment: Probably your problem is here: `context!!`. From where the context comes from?

Comment: this is dialogfragment, it gives context

Comment: Check `context` and `noteID` before put not null assertion

Comment: I thought that this `!!` check it, or how I have to do it?

Comment: Use like this: context?. instead of context!!. You should follow the mentioned thread to work it out